# Nextjs - Get protected reuqests from getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js, laravel-sanctum, next-auth

I am working with next js app. For backend I use laravel with sanctum autentication. I want to implement credential authentication (username, password) using laravel sanctum and nextjs SPA app. All these working with client side. But I can not access to protected request in getServerSideProps. It requires crsf token.

pages/login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import api from '@/util/api';
import { logIn } from '@/util/auth';

const LogInPage = () => {
  const [formInput, setFormInput] = useState({ username: '', password: '' });
          
  const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    api()
      .get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
      .then(() => {
        api()
          .post('/api/login', formInput)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.error) {
              console.log(response.data.error);
            } else {
              router.push('/')
            }
          });
      });
  };
```

pages/index.js (protected route)

```
const Home = ({ user }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    api()
      .get('/api/users')
      .then((response) => {
        setUsers(response.data);
      });
  }, []);

}
```

Question: How to do it with getServerSideProps? Or how to use this implementation using NextAuth.js? Or maybe need bridge between client to server

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  let users = [];
  api()
    .get('/api/users')
    .then((response) => {
      users = response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

  return {
    props: { users },
  };
}
```

'/api/users' route is protected, requires authentication, so it responds 401 unauthorized

Comment: You have access to the cookies sent in the request in [`getServerSideProps`'s context object](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) through `context.req.cookies`.